# Sugarcrm Emails showing variables instead of values

Tags: sugarcrm

When a user requests for reset password link, he's receiving the name with variables (`$contact_name`) instead of user's actual name.

Comment: please append your email template in question.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Users should receive emails with there names and not with vairables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED !!! :) ....

```
$contact_user_user_name
```

worked for me. Thanks to all those who tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
For using user variables use $contact_user instead of $contact. So for the user's name use $contact_user_name.

Original:
View the source of the email and check for any spaces inside of $contact_name or other junk characters that are breaking up the variable. You can view the source by clicking on the HTML button, I believe. Clean up the variable and it should then work.

Comment: Thanks egg, but there is no junk characters inside the variable.

Comment: I misread the issue and have updated my answer. You need to use $contact_user_name instead of $contact_name since it is for a user record.

Comment: Sorry egg, now it's showing $contact_user_name but not the value.

Comment: Is there any other solution? Please.